# override empty method in custom view and handle it in MainActivity

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener, android-custom-view, overriding

To make thinks simple, I have made a custom calendar view (RelativeLayout). Events (linearLayouts) are placed inside it. When I click on the event I want to be able to do something, but I want this something to be done in my MainActivity. In other words I want to override the empty method in my custom view and handle it in my MainActivity.

```
                    eventView.setTag(event.getDatabaseId());
                    eventView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.d("test", "" + v.getTag());
                            onEventClick((int) v.getTag());
                        }
                    });
                    eventView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            onEventLongClick((int) v.getTag());
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
    }

...

    public void onEventClick(int eventId) {

    }

    public void onEventLongClick(int eventId) {

    }
```

So in my MainActivity I instantiate my view:

```
    cv = ((CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_view));
```

I want to do something like:

```
    cv = ((CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_view)) {
        @Override
        public void onEventClick(int eventId) {
            // here I will fetch the data and display a dialog
        }

        @Override
        public void onEventLongClick(int eventId) {
            // here I will fetch the data and display a dialog
        }
    };
```

I want to be able to use my calendar else where so this is why I don't want to tie the click functionality inside my custom view

I tried making my view abstract but got nowhere either.

EDIT: eventView's are in a viewpager

Comment: I don't think you can do that. findViewById returns a View, you can't make an anonymous class off it

Comment: oh I know, it was just a demonstration showing that I wanted to bring it to the MainActivity somehow

Comment: Could you show your full custom View class? I would assume you could define your own interface and pass it into the other class as a parameter

Comment: I would but it's like 600 lines. I think the answer below will solve it but thanks!

Comment: Yes, the below way is the recommended approach. I assumed you already had done that, which is why I wanted to see the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Interface` on your custom view.

> In its most common form, an interface is a group of related methods with empty bodies. You can find more detailed instructions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

So in your case I assume you have a `RelativeLayout` as your custom view

```
public class MyCalendarLayout extends RelativeLayouts{

    //Your constructor methods

    public interface MyEventListener {
        public void onEventClicked();
        public void onEventLongClicked();
    }

    private MyEventListener myEventListener;

        public void setListener(MyEventListener myEventListener) {
        this.myEventListener= myEventListener;
    }
}
```

Then on your `Activity` you can use it like this

```
myCustomView.setListener(new MyEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEventClicked() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onEventLongClicked() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Or you can use

`YourActivity extends Activity implements MyEventListener`

and you can call

```
myCustomView.setListener(this);
```

on your activity and let the handle override methods to your activity.

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems